# Pandas read_csv function is reading csv header wrong

Tags: python, csv, pandas

See example csv file below:

```
A,B,C 
d,e,f 
g,h,i
```

The first row with the capital letters are *my headings*.

I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", header=0, sep=",", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

And the data frame that is created looks like this with the headings messed up.

```
  B C 
A 
d e f
g h i
```

Anyone know why or how I can fix this manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that when you pass `index_col=0` argument to `read_csv()` , it takes the `0th` column as the index column, hence in your resulting DataFrame, `A` is the index.

If you do not want to take `A` as the index, you should just omit the `index_col=0` argument. Example -

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=True)
```

I removed some other keyword arguments as well -

- `header=0` , header is 0 by default if `names` argument is not passed.
- `sep=','` , seperator is `','` by default.